# How to add Text on a transparent image using ImageMagick without getting it pixelated?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using imagemagick to create bunch of images by creating an empty transparent image and overlaying text on top of it.

Issue is that text doesn't appear crisp and is pixelated.

I'm using following command to create image.

```
convert -background "rgba(255, 255 ,255, -1)" -font "/tmp/fonts/AlfaSlabOne-Regular.ttf" -pointsize "62.270833333333336" -fill "#000000" label:"Sub Heading Goes Here" -gravity southeast -splice 10x10 -gravity northwest -splice 10x10 /tmp/pitch/sub_heading.png
```

Result that I'm getting is...

[image]

What I want is...

[image]

Comment: Using your command to create the text image in ImageMagick 6.9.8.10 Q16 Mac OS X, it looks fine to me. You have one issue, though it does not seem to matter. Negative transparency values are not allowed in your color, rgba(255, 255 ,255, -1). Values for alpha range from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque). Why are you using a white background for the transparency. You could just use -background none for rgba(0,0,0,0). My main question is what commands did you use to overlay that image on the background image and can you provide the background image? What is your Imagemagic version?

Comment: You could just use -annotate to write your text on the background image directly. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/. That even allows an underfloor if you want to contrast the text with some color rather than writing it over the background image directly.

Comment: If you wanted to add a 10 pixel border, it would have been easier to use -border 10 than two instances of -splice. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

Comment: I do not think fractional pointsizes are used. They appear to be rounded to an integer value.

Comment: The version of ImageMagick I'm using is ImageMagick 7.0.1-5 Q16 x86_64 2016-05-19

Comment: We are adding text to a transparent image. Later we overlay this image on a video. The screenshot above is from video.

Comment: Making font size non-decimal seems to be solving the problem.

Comment: If that does not solve the issue, then post one frame of the video, so I can see if overlaying the transparent background text image onto it is working. Also post your command line for the overlay process.